# X-Editable Custom Pop up hover Content Input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

[image: i want to create like this]

Is there a way to custom content in pop hover input in x-editable?
I want to custom date range picker inside the pop hover

Thanks for experts

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to style your date picker - https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/blob/master/src/inputs/date/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css has the CSS for the date picker.

Just override these styles by including your CSS **after** the x-editable / bootstrap CSS. The class names and CSS is pretty self explanatory (and for the rest you have F12 Dev Tools!)